# Changing offset from within onBefore - LocalScroll jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, offset, scrollto

I'm using localScroll plugin by Ariel Flesler and everything works fine. I've got one problem though. I can't find out how to change the offset parameter from within onBefore.

e.g.

```
$('#menu').localScroll({

    hash: true,
    offset: {
        top: -60,
        left: 0
    },
    onBefore: function(e, anchor, $target) {
        if (something) {
            offset.top = -100;
        }
    }

});​
```

I would be grateful if anyone could help:)

Answer (score 2):

The `onBefore` setting can use `this.someSetting` to return a value to a setting.

[Ariel Flesler: jQuery.LocalScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html)

With that in mind you can do the following:

```
$('#htmlObject').localScroll({
     onBefore: function(){
          if(something){
               this.offset = someNumber;
          }
     }
});
```

So the solution you already have almost works, you just need to replace your `offset.top` with `this.offset` and you should see the results you are looking for.